# throw new InvalidConfigError(`topic name is illegal, cannot be longer than ${allowedTopicLength} characters)

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Need help on following error , same setup works on localhost but when I try to run on production server received following error.

1. Kafka and zookeeper are setup on same server

===========================

```
/var/www/html/kafka-server/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/utils.js:23
      throw new InvalidConfigError(`topic name is illegal, cannot be longer th
                                   ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/kafka-server/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/highLevelConsumer.js:11:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

===========================

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758833/unexpected-token-illegal-while-running-node-js-mocha-test

Comment: Did you use an extremely long topic which exceeds 249 characters?

Comment: I am getting on the below code:
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Producer = kafka.Producer,
    client = new kafka.Client('localhost:2181'),
    producer = new Producer(client);

Comment: You did not show how you invoke producer.send/producer.produce